# Integrating AppsFlyer to Google Analytics property migrated from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, appsflyer

Our mobile app tracks app installs with AppsFlyer. We now need to track installs with Firebase. Our Firebase app links to Google Analytics. So, we are trying to integrate Appsflyer to GA and get AppsFlyer to send install events to GA automatically.

Following the link below, AppsFlyer requires GA's tracking_id as the Account_Id for the integration. As our GA property was linked from Firebase project, there isn't any tracking_id. Is there any other firebase id we can use for this?

https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207040616-Google-Analytics-integrations#intro

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, Firebase for analytics doesn't included the GA ID that you need in order to integrate GA with AppsFlyer.

What you can do is integrate [AppsFlyer with Firebase and GTM](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/210353513-Using-Firebase-and-Google-Tag-Manager-with-AppsFlyer#sending-install-events).

Note that this integration requires you to send installs to Firebase as in-app events. It doesn't really send installs to Firebase. The link I included takes you to a section in the article that explains how to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do it through GA Integration to reduce the code changes. Unfortunately, it doesn't sound possible. It would be nice if AppsFlyer provides a way to integrate to FB like GA.